# MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH Config variable isn't being honoured

Tags: heroku, imagemagick, config

I have followed this guide to configure the policy.xml file:

https://help.heroku.com/RFDJQSG3/how-can-i-override-imagemagick-settings-in-a-policy-xml-file

However, when this config env var is in place and I run the `identify -list policy` command it still only reads policies from the default path and doesn't also search the new one.

Config var:
MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH set to "/app/.magick/:/etc/ImageMagick-6/" using command:

`heroku config:set MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH="/app/.magick/:/etc/ImageMagick-6/"`

Output:

```
Path: /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
  Policy: Resource
    name: disk
    value: 1GiB
  Policy: Resource
    name: map
    value: 512MiB
  Policy: Resource
    name: memory
    value: 256MiB
  Policy: Resource
    name: area
    value: 128MB
  Policy: Resource
    name: height
    value: 16KP
  Policy: Resource
    name: width
    value: 16KP
  Policy: Delegate
    rights: None 
    pattern: URL
  Policy: Delegate
    rights: None 
    pattern: HTTPS
  Policy: Delegate
    rights: None 
    pattern: HTTP
  Policy: Path
    rights: None 
    pattern: @*

Path: [built-in]
  Policy: Undefined
    rights: None
```

Im on a Ruby heroku-18 Stack and my policy found in `/app/.magick/policy.xml` contains:

```
<policymap xmlns="">
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read | write" pattern="HTTPS" />
</policymap>
```

Have any idea how I can get this config var working?

Comment: Which policy.xml file did you edit? It can be in several places and you might have set one that is check last or later in the list from the default one. See https://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php. The .magick location is low in the list (the older location that was equivalent to the newer .config). Best to edit it higher in the list.

Comment: Please show your **exact** `heroku config:set` command

Comment: @MarkSetchell the config:set command is a copy and paste from the one in the document from Heroku. https://help.heroku.com/RFDJQSG3/how-can-i-override-imagemagick-settings-in-a-policy-xml-file

Comment: @fmw42 I created my own in the app root `/app/.magick/policy.xml` should I be placing it somewhere else?

Comment: Your command appears to have spaces around the `=` and to have lost the double quotes.

Comment: @MarkSetchell sorry thats just to show what my config variable is set at. not the actual command that set it. I'll make it more clear.

Comment: Remove the `xmlns=""` attribute from the `<policymap>` element. Might be throwing off the xml library.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out putting your config file as root looks like `app/.magick` however that doesn't mean the `.magick` directory needs to be created in your Rails `app` directory.

Moving `.magick` directory to the true root of my app made it work.

Comment: How were you able to move the `.magick` directory to the true root? Is it still part of your git commit?